# Compare 2 tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables, A1 and A2. I want to compare these two tables. I tried inner join but it doesn't give the required result.

These are the data in these tables,

**Table A1**

```
No. Address 
1  abc
1  abc
1  def
1  def
```

**Table A2**

```
No. Address
1    def
1    abc
1    abc
1    def
```

These two tables can only be joined by using `No.` column. So if I use INNER JOIN it gives 16 rows. I don't want that, I want only 4 rows to be displayed. This should be the output:

```
No.   Address   eq
1     abc      #
1     abc      *
1     abc      #
1     abc      #
```

Last column is displayed if address in A1 is equal to A2

Comment: What is the primary key of each table?  Clearly it isn't `No.`

Comment: but last row in both table equal too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for records that exist in A1 table but not in A2 table:

```
SELECT * FROM A1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A2 WHERE A2.Id = A1.Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use case

select case when tablea1.address=tablea2.address then '*'
       else '#' end as eq from tablea1 inner join tablea2 on tablea1.=tablea2.

hope it helps you.