# Iterate to compare 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare

I have a table `tbl_user` with the columns `login` and `device`.
The `login` is the unique id and the `device` is an integer which changes.
What I am trying to accomplish here is to archive all the `device` for each `login` using a new table `tbl_user_arhcive`.

E.g. for `login = 201530` the `device` value is `123456` at the current time. I need to check the `tbl_user_archive` if the specified `login` exist with the specific device value. If it exists then I will not insert it otherwise I will insert it in the `tbl_user_archive`. That way I will keep an archive with all the device values(unique) the login ever had.

I have no idea how to start with it. I found some similar questions on SO but they didn't help me to understand how to solve this.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354721/trying-to-compare-2-tables-with-multiple-joins)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107013/compare-2-tables-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_user_archive(login, device)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        login, 
        device
    FROM tbl_user tu
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM tbl_user_archive
        WHERE login = tu.login
        AND device = tu.device
    )
```

If you have a unique constraint on `login, device` on `tbl_user`, then you can remove the `DISTINCT` as it will just add an additional `DISTINCT SORT` operation and will increase execution time.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as expected. Please fix a typo on `t.login`

Comment: Glad to have been of help!